# Hypothetical past or present

Tags: irrealis-mood

> 1. If all of us could follow diets, we'd all have reached our goals.

It is from a translation test. I am wondering if it makes more sense to say

> 2. If all of us <**could have followed/had followed>** diets, we'd all **have reached** our goals.

Because the things that affect the present must have happened in the past.  And we should use *have done something* to refer to the past, as in

> 3. If I had worked harder, I'd have reached my goal

Comment: Past conditional usage is: If all of us had followed [simple past] diets, we'd have reached our goals. OR First conditional:  If all of us followed diets, we'd reach our goals. However, if you are translating from French, which is what it sounds like (suivre un régime) that would be: stay on a diet. "follow a diet" means stick to the items on the list of a diet.